# jQuery dialog in Wordpress buttons appear on the left instead of the right

Tags: css, wordpress, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a large table that I want to appear in a dialog created by jQuery UI.

The development version I created worked correctly but note that this was not using the default Wordpress versions of jQuery and jQuery UI. I registered versions of both libraries for the purposes of the development version.

Using the same script and dialog contents I attempted to reproduce the dialog for my blog using the default versions of the jQuery libraries.
This produces a result where the dialog opens but in the display the default close button found in the title bar is on the left. When you mouse over this close button the icon moves down, but it still closes on a click.
In addition the resize icon appears in the bottom left as does an additional close button I added.

This led me to suspect that I have a css conflict  between my table and the jquery UI css. I've noted posts suggesting that there is a problem with jQuery UI 1.8.16 and dialogs with a large amount of content.

However, I can't locate the css for the default jQuery UI library, I'm assuming that it must exist.

The easy answer to this problem would be to deregister the default versions and register external versions but that seems like a waste when the functionality is already in Wordpress.

Questions:

1. Where do I find the css in Wordpress for the default jquery UI
2. Any suggestions as to what may be the cause of this problem

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1) The CSS files are located at /wp-includes/css/jquery-ui-dialog.css (compressed) & /wp-includes/css/jquery-ui-dialog.css (development).

2) We'd need to see an example to have an idea of what the problem might be.

Answer (score 0):

All the styling for that button is located on line 69 in:

/wp-content/plugins/mailchimp//css/flick/flick.css

Comment: I believe that css is for the mailchimp function. I did find the css for the jquery UI its located in wp-includes/css, or at least the dialog css appears to be in that folder.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the display issue by simply adding the CSS files from the jquery UI theme. Once that was in place everything displayed correct. Not elegant but it solved the problem quickly.